# facebook "i like" question

Tags: facebook, page-title

I'm using facebook "i like" on my site. facebook uses the title tag of the page as what the person likes. is there a way to add a different title instead of defaulting to the title tag of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [OpenGraph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) property "title" inside the "head" tag of your site for that:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title for FB" />
```

You can then use [linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) to check if what Facebook thinks about your page is okay with you.

Comment: do you know the opengraph property for twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but you can point it to a different URL using the `href` attribute. Your website could return your modified page title at that URL.

*Source: [API docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)*

Answer (score 0):

like alessandro says. Its possible using the href atribute

```
<fb:like layout="button_count" class="like_button" href="your url stuf here"></fb:like>
```

I use php to put dinamically the href stuff, so using some RewriteRule on my htaccess and the tittle in the generated html , i can show what ever i whant, when they press the like button